# Starting chained activity within Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

According to the pattern

```
Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_... );
i.setFlags(...);
i.setCategory(...);
startActivity( i );
```

Is it possible to chain (or to stack, whatever you call it) two `Intent`'s then start the chain with a single `startActivity()`? *The two `Intent`'s must execute one after the other, not in parallel.*

I'm targeting ICS 4.0.3 and higher.

Comment: Expalin more about `chain two Intent's` what you mean? and yes it's possible to  launch multiple new activities using [startActivities (Intent[] intents)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivities%28android.content.Intent[],%20android.os.Bundle%29)

Comment: Well, I mean what you explained in your comment.

Comment: then use `startActivities` to start more then one Activity

Answer (score 0):

This will work just fine:

```
context.startActivity(intent1);
context.startActivity(intent2);
```

What exactly is the purpose?

Comment: In your answer, what assures me that intent2 will be done *after* intent1? I just want to uninstall an application before re-installing it with a lower version code (downgrade seems to be forbidden in 4.2.2...?) Well... the app in question is the one that calls these intents. There cannot be any code between the two lines.

Comment: In that case give intent1 a bundle which contains parameters to - if present - let it start intent2. That way you can be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Use startActivityForResult() to execute the first Intent. Once the Activity is done, execute second Intent in onActivityResult() callback.

```
public void launchChainActivities() {
    this.mFirstIntent = new Intent(this, First.class);
    this.mSecondIntent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
    startActivityForResult(this.mFirstIntent, 100);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode == 100) {
       startActivity(this.mSecondIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot be that. The first activity is to uninstall the current app and the second one is to re-install it. Messy but it seems I have to do that to be able to overwrite an app with an older version of itself, without any user interaction, under Android 4.2...